# Generic Mediatr IRequestPostProcessor with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-5.0, mediatr

I want to use Mediatr's `IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>` "post-processing" [behaviour processor](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors#built-in-behaviors).

The non-generic [sample](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/49f9821547db1f86f01851baa1c1935b12029d06/test/MediatR.Tests/Pipeline/RequestPostProcessorTests.cs#L31) works for me.

But I want a generic one:

```cs
public class MyPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>
  where TRequest : notnull
{

  public Task Process(TRequest request, TResponse response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

}
```

That processor is as simple as can be, and **should** be called for all requests. However it is not called, because it's generic.

Digging into this I discovered that Autofac for a very long time did [not support](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/issues/128) open generics, which led to this problem. But since [6.2.0](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/releases/tag/v6.2.0) Autofac does support this.

I am using this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/7.2.0):

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.2.0" />
```

But that doesn't seem to use the version that fixes that issue. So I did this:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="6.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="7.2.0" />
```

Which definitely pulls in the correct version. But the problem remains - the processor is not called.

Is there some alternative or workaround to get this working with Autofac?